# Using QAbstractListModel in ListView

Tags: qt, listview, qt5, qtquick2, qabstractlistmodel

I'm new with Qt , so please bear with me .

I've successfully managed to populate a ListView from a StringList and a QList of Object*

What I'm struggling now with is to populate a ListView in QML using a class defined in C++ that derives QAbstractListModel.

Here's the prototype of my CPP class :

```
class MessageListEntryModel : public QAbstractListModel
{

Q_OBJECT
public:

enum eMLERoleTypes
{
    MLERT_MSG = Qt::UserRole+1,
    MLERT_COLOR
};

                                MessageListEntryModel(QObject* parent=0);
        virtual                 ~MessageListEntryModel();

        void                    AddEntry(QString aMessage, QColor aColor);

        // pure virtuals implementations
        QVariant                data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
        int                     rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const ;
        int                     columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const ;
        QModelIndex             index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
        QModelIndex             parent(const QModelIndex &child) const ;

        QHash<int,QByteArray>   roleNames();
private:
 QList<MessageEntry*> m_vpMessages;
```

MessageEntry is a simple class that contains 2 memebers , a QColor and a QString (the class doesn't extend QObject).

I had to implement all the above functions since they're pure virtual in an underlying class (is this normal? so far in tutorials/samples people mentioned only about roleNames and data).

The implementation of roleNames and data are as following :

```
QHash<int,QByteArray>  MessageListEntryModel::roleNames()
{
    QHash<int,QByteArray> rez;
    rez[MLERT_MSG]="message";
    rez[MLERT_COLOR]="messagecolor";
    return rez;
}

QVariant MessageListEntryModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    qDebug()<<" Data asked for "<<index.row()<<" and role "<<role;
    if (index.row()<0 || index.row()>=m_vpMessages.size())
    {
        return QVariant();
    }
    MessageEntry* entry = m_vpMessages[index.row()];
    if (role == MLERT_MSG)
    {
        return QVariant::fromValue(entry->message);
    } else if (role == MLERT_COLOR)
    {
        return QVariant::fromValue(entry->messageColor);
    }
    // should be unreachable code
    return QVariant();
}
```

The QML portion of the List View is something like this :

```
 ListView {
    id: quickMessageListdata
    model: quickListModel
    delegate: Rectangle {

        width: 400
        height: 25
        color:"#000000"
        Text{
            text: model.message
            color: model.messagecolor
        }
    }
```

So far this is my understanding on how to implement things in CPP and QML.
For linking these two, I use the following code :

```
MessageListEntryModel* model =new MessageListEntryModel();
// Add various entries
...
// assign model in QML
m_pViewRef->rootContext()->setContextProperty("quickListModel",model);
```

With the code above, when running nothing is displayed in the ListView and I'm getting the following errors :

```
Unable to assign [undefined] to QString

Unable to assign [undefined] to QColor
```

I'm also registering the model class to be exported to QML (don't know if this is necessary) :

```
qmlRegisterType<MessageListEntryModel> ("dlti.exported",1,0,"MessageListEntryModel");
```

So it's quite obvious that either I missuderstood the proper use of a QAbstractListItem derived class OR I miss a simple vital key information.

I would appreciate some pointers to some relevant samples / tutorials (one that also shows you how to properly access data from the model in QML, since I've noticed that in CPP it never passes through the data function).

Also please notice that I'm using qt5 , so qt4.8 samples won't do the trick.

EDIT

After long hours of frustrations, I finally managed what was wrong with the damn thing :

My roleNames function signature was wrong !
The correct signature for overload is :

```
protected :
      QHash<int,QByteArray> roleNames() const;
```

Please notice the protected and the const modifiers.

After declaring the function the correct way , it all worked fine.

For further notice, implementing data and rowCount was sufficient :).

Thanks for the help.
I will accept BaCaRoZzo's answer since I only manged to figure this out after looking over the code from the example.

As a side note, it works well with both message and model.message.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How do you implement the addition method? You should use a method like in the example provided in my comment.

From the [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html):

> An insertRows() implementation **must call beginInsertRows() before
>   inserting** new rows into the data structure, and it **must call
>   endInsertRows() immediately afterwards**.

You should have something like:

```
void MessageListEntryModel::add(params...)
{
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());   // kindly provided by superclass
    // object creation based on params...
    m_vpMessages << objectCreated;
    endInsertRows();                                          // kindly provided by superclass
}
```

with

```
int MessageListEntryModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent) const {
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return m_vpMessages.count();
}
```

Also, @Jonathan Mee comment is correct: use just the role names inside the delegate as you defined them in the model. If everything else is correct *that* is the way to access data.

---

One of the best documentation piece to understand C++ models implementation and usage is the [Model subclassing reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#model-subclassing-reference). In this document is clearly depicted which are the most important methods to subclass and for what purposes.

As for the methods to implement, it really depends on the needs. Depending on the possible actions on the model, different methods should be implemented (refer to the above link for full details). A model for a `ListView` in which items can be added/removed can inherit from `QAbstractListModel` and just rely on the default implementations for most of the functions. You just need `data()`, `roleNames()` and `rowCount()`, as you already saw in most examples.

If instead you also need to *edit* data not just adding/removing it, then you also need other functions, particularly `setData()`. It is also *your* duty to notify the attached view(s) with any modification of the model occurred in `setData()`, via the signal `dataChanged()`. Refer again to the above provide subclassing reference.

Note also that, if the `add` method is modified with the `Q_INVOKABLE` modifier, i.e. it is declared as

```
Q_INVOKABLE void add(params...);
```

in the model header, you can also call it from QML (since the model is set as a context property) and you can write, for instance:

```
ListView {
    id: quickMessageListdata
    model: quickListModel
    delegate: Rectangle {

        width: 400
        height: 25
        color:"#000000"
        Text{
            text: model.message
            color: model.messagecolor
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        quickListModel.add(params)
        quickListModel.add(params)      
    }
}
```

to insert items in the view as soon as the view is created. Clearly the same approach can be applied to other QML signals so that you can react to QML events and trigger addition/removal behaviours.

Finally, you don't need to register the model with `qmlRegisterType`. For your current requirement it is superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... I'm not super familiar with QML but I believe that this is your problem: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html#qabstractitemmodel

According to the link it looks like you need to change your `Text` block to:

```
Text{
    text: message
    color: messagecolor
}
```

Further reading: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/5491

Comment: Doing what you suggested gives me ReferenceError "message" is not defined (Same for message color). I am aware of the tutorial you linked (it's actually my starting point). Problem is the tutorial is incomplete / the code from the tutorial isn't working (eg : you need to implement more than just rolemodels function).

Comment: That very same example is under `Examples\<QT_VERSION>\quick\models\abstractitemmodel` inside Qt installation folder. Just open the corresponding `.pro` and have a look around.

Answer (score 0):

I've also experienced hard times before when creating own list models with Qt C++. To avoid the development overhead for a C++ model, I started to use *QSyncable* (a existing QAbstractListModel implementation by Ben Lau). You can find it on [GitHub](https://github.com/benlau/qsyncable) here.

The best part of the project is the JsonListModel QML type. It can transform any variant JSON list that you create or fetch in QML to a full-featured QML ListModel. This saves a lot of time and effort for applications that e.g. work with JSON or REST services. You can find a detailed guide how it works [here](https://v-play.net/apps/avoid-cpp-models-qt).